# Staying DRY in rust

Tags: reference, dry, rust

Sometimes I have to act on information that is expressed in a long sequence, like:

```
f1(f2(f3).f4(x,f5(y,z))).f6().f7()
```

(not necessarily that, just any long sequence you don't want to repeat).  And I may need to reference that multiple times, with other code in-between.  Like this:

```
fn myfunc(v: &T) -> X {
  match v.func(func(v.func().func())).func() {
    ...
  }
  .. other stuff ..
  match v.func(func(v.func().func())).func() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The value is not movable, so I cannot assign it to a variable and then reference the variable twice like in other languages, so essentially I find myself writing the same sequence of function calls multiple times.  I tried something like this

```
let x = &( ... )
```

and then using this

```
*x
```

but this didn't work.  I suppose I could use a macro, but then it would be recomputed each time (... which isn't too bad as most of the function calls are just sugar for the compiler and type system), but that's the best I have solved this so far.  Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean is not movable? What is the result (type) of whis computed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is not [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html), then you either need to copy it, or pass by reference. E.g. suppose it was computing a value of type `T`. I suppose the problem you're currently meeting is

```
fn foo(x: T) { ... }
fn bar(x: T) { ... }


let your_thing = f1(f2(f3).f4(x,f5(y,z))).f6().f7();

foo(your_thing);
bar(your_thing); // error: use of moved value
```

The correct fix is changing the `foo` lines to

```
fn foo(x: &T) { ... }

foo(&your_thing);
```

or, the `foo` call to `foo(your_thing.clone())` (if `T` is `Clone`). You can decide which one is appropriate by thinking about what sort of ownership `foo` needs of the `T`: if it needs full ownership (e.g. passing it to different tasks), you should take it by value `foo(x: T)`; on the other hand, if it only needs a view on to the data (i.e. no ownership), then take a reference `foo(x: &T)`.

See also ["Moves vs Copy in Rust"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253573/1256624) for some background on moving and copying. It includes an explanation of why the `&(...)` + `*x` solution isn't work: can't move out from behind a reference (although, in this case it will never work, because moving out *twice* is illegal anyway).

---

The same reasoning applies for pattern matching: if you only need a reference, you can take a reference into the value of interest via `ref`. E.g. imagine you're computing an `Option<T>`.

```
let x = v.func(func(v.func().func())).func()

match x {
    Some(ref y) => { /* y is a &T */ ... }
    None => { ... }
}

// the last `match` can move `x`
match x {
     Some(y) => { /* y is a T */ ... }
     None => { ... }
}
```

If the first match does need ownership of some parts of `x`, you can either `clone` `x` itself, or only those parts you need after matching with `ref`.

Comment: I embarrassingly don't have a concrete example as I moved past it in the code.  But I recall it being like this:

    `fn myfunc(var: &T) -> X {
    match var.something().somethingelse(blah) { }
    .. more code ...
    match var.something().somethingelse(blah) { }
    }`

Comment: The error showed up on the 'let x=' part, being that I can't move out of a reference something or other.  But maybe it wouldn't have if my matches used 'ref' as you say.  I'll accept this and come back here if I run into it again.