# what's going on when returning pointers in rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm reading the [return pointers part](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-pointers.html#returning-pointers) of Rust Guide. 
Here is a sample code of it:

```
struct BigStruct {
    one: int,
    two: int,
    // etc
    one_hundred: int,
}

fn foo(x: Box<BigStruct>) -> BigStruct {
    return *x;
}

fn main() {
    let x = box BigStruct {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        one_hundred: 100,
    };

    let y = box foo(x);
}
```

The strong part of the following explanation confuses me:

> There is no copy in this code. main allocates enough room for the `box , passes a pointer to that memory into foo as x, **and then foo writes the value straight into that pointer. This writes the return value directly into the allocated box.**

having read [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253344/move-vs-copy-in-rust/24253573#24253573), I still don't get the *no-copy* point here.

Does function `foo` return a copy of `*x`?
If it does, how to understand the explanation?
If it does not, is it related to ownership and borrowing?

I understand the concept of ownership and borrowing, I just don't know when it happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide is trying to tell you that the code is behaving as if it was written this way:

```
struct BigStruct {
    one: int,
    two: int,
    // etc
    one_hundred: int,
}

fn foo(x: Box<BigStruct>, result: &mut BigStruct) {
    *result = *x;
}

fn main() {
    let x = box BigStruct {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        one_hundred: 100,
    };

    unsafe {
        let mut y = box std::mem::uninitialized();
        foo(x, &mut *y);
    }
}
```

`main` creates a `Box` and passes a pointer to the box's interior to `foo` as an input argument. This way, `foo` can store the result value there directly rather than returning it and having `main` copy it into the box.

There is a copy happening in `foo` (from the first box to the second box), but if `foo` wasn't writing directly into the box, there would be two copies (possibly one from the first box to the stack in `foo`, then from the stack to the second box in `main`).

P.S.: I think there's an error in the guide. It says:

> passes a pointer to that memory into foo as **x**

but `x` is the box from which we're trying to copy, not the new box... Rather, it passes a pointer as a hidden argument.

Comment: It seems to be a reasonable and correct answer based on what I have read recently. I remember that C++ have used the similar mechanism.

Comment: btw, do you have any more detailed clues on the topics, copying and moving...? I almost have read all the articles i can get, except the source code.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question for this. We'll be able to give you a more elaborate answer this way.