# Why is the Copy trait needed for default (struct valued) array initialization?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

When I define a struct like this, I can pass it to a function by value without adding anything specific:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyType {
    member: u16,
}

fn my_function(param: MyType) {
    println!("param.member: {}", param.member);
}
```

When I want to create an array of `MyType` instances with a default value

```
fn main() {
    let array = [MyType { member: 1234 }; 100];
    println!("array[42].member: ", array[42].member);
}
```

The Rust compiler tells me:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyType: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     let array = [MyType { member: 1234 }; 100];
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `MyType`
   |
   = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

When I implement `Copy` and `Clone`, everything works:

```
impl Copy for MyType {}
impl Clone for MyType {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        MyType {
            member: self.member.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

1. Why do I need to specify an empty `Copy` trait implementation?
2. Is there a simpler way to do this or do I have to re-think something?
3. Why does it work when passing an instance of `MyType` to the function by value? My guess is that it is being moved, so there is no copy in the first place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Contrary to C/C++, Rust has very explicit distinction between types which are copied and which are moved. Note that this is only a semantic distinction; on the implementation level move *is* a shallow bytewise copy, however, the compiler places certain restrictions on what you can do with variables you moved from.

By default *every* type is only moveable (non-copyable). It means that values of such types are moved around:

```
let x = SomeNonCopyableType::new();
let y = x;
x.do_something();      // error!
do_something_else(x);  // error!
```

You see, the value which was stored in `x` has been moved to `y`, and so you can't do anything with `x`.

Move semantics is a very important part of ownership concept in Rust. You can read more on it [in the official guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html).

Some types, however, are simple enough so their bytewise copy is also their semantic copy: if you copy a value byte-by-byte, you will get a new completely independent value. For example, primitive numbers are such types. Such property is designated by `Copy` trait in Rust, i.e. if a type implements `Copy`, then values of this type are implicitly copyable. `Copy` does not contain methods; it exists solely to mark that implementing types have certain property and so it is usually called a marker trait (as well as few other traits which do similar things).

However, it does not work for all types. For example, structures like dynamically allocated vectors cannot be automatically copyable: if they were, the address of the allocation contained in them would be byte-copied too, and then the destructor of such vector will be run twice over the same allocation, causing this pointer to be freed twice, which is a memory error.

So by default custom types in Rust are not copyable. But you can opt-in for it using `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` (or, as you noticed, using direct `impl`; they are equivalent, but `derive` usually reads better):

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct MyType {
    member: u16
}
```

(deriving `Clone` is necessary because `Copy` inherits `Clone`, so everything which is `Copy` must also be `Clone`)

If your type can be automatically copyable in principle, that is, it doesn't have an associated destructor and all of its members are `Copy`, then with `derive` your type will also be `Copy`.

You can use `Copy` types in array initializer precisely because the array will be initialized with bytewise copies of the value used in this initializer, so your type has to implement `Copy` to designate that it indeed *can* be automatically copied.

The above was the answer to 1 and 2. As for 3, yes, you are absolutely correct. It does work precisely because the value is moved into the function. If you tried to use a variable of `MyType` type after you passed it into the function, you would quickly notice an error about using a moved value.

Comment: "*Contrary to C/C++, Rust has very explicit distinction between types which are copied and which are moved.*" What do you mean? C does not have those concepts to begin with. C++ has them, but they are explicit and part of the type system.

Comment: The question is semantics. In C, everything is copied, even those types which should logically be moved, and there is no support from language to enforce or simplify it (i.e. you have to write the move logic explicitly). C++ is similar, except that in it, there are move-related tools in the language (move constructor, `std::move`, etc). However, these tools are very explicit and error-prone, i.e. you need to not forget to call `std::move`, and you need to implement the move constructor correctly. Also, I'm not quite sure how move is visible in the type system in C++?

Comment: "*C++ is similar ... However, these tools are very explicit and error-prone*" That's false. C++ types are statically copyable, moveable, both or none. You can't "*forget to call `std::move`*" if the type requires it. *you need to implement the move constructor correctly* The compiler does it for you for the equivalent semantics in Rust. The actual advantage Rust has here is affine types.

Comment: "*how move is visible in the type system in C++?*" It is baked into the type system. You can even query the compiler for those traits at compile-time (like a subset of static reflection) and tweak generated code accordingly (including static branching etc.). Rust will get this too with the const eval efforts, but it's a hard feature to specify and to implement and thus it is less powerful than C++ in this case at the moment.

Comment: Okay, then probably my knowledge of C++ is not enough. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Don't mention it!

Answer (score 5):

> Why do I need to specify an empty Copy trait implementation?

`Copy` is a special built-in trait such that `T` implementing `Copy` represents that it is safe to duplicate a value of type `T` with a shallow byte copy.

This simple definition mean that one just needs to tell the compiler those semantics are correct, since there's no fundamental change in run-time behaviour: both a move (a non-`Copy` type) and a "copy" are shallow byte copies, it's just a question of if the source is usable later. See [an older answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253573/1256624).

(The compiler will complain if the contents of `MyType` isn't `Copy` itself; previously it would be automatically implemented, but that all changed [with opt-in built-in traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md).)

Creating an array is duplicating the value via shallow copies, and this is guaranteed to be safe if `T` is `Copy`. It is safe in more general situations, [#5244](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/5244) covers some of them, but at the core, a non-`Copy` struct won't be able to be used to create a fixed-length array automatically because the compiler can't tell that the duplication is safe/correct.

> Is there a simpler way to do this or do I have to re-think something (I'm coming from C)?

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct MyType {
    member: u16
}
```

will insert the appropriate empty implementation (`#[derive]` works with several other traits, e.g. one often sees `#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]`.)

> Why does it work when passing an instance of `MyType` to the function by value? My guess is that it is being moved, so there is no copy in the first place.

Well, without calling the function one doesn't see the move vs. copy behaviour (if you were to call it twice the same non-`Copy` value, the compiler would emit an error about moved values). But, a "move" and a "copy" are essentially the same on the machine. All by-value uses of a value are shallow copies semantically in Rust, just like in C.