# Use C-Like Array of Struct in Rust

Tags: c, arrays, struct, rust

I need help converting the following C code to Rust.

```
#define v0   0x0
#define v1   0x1
#define v2   0x2
#define v3   0x3

struct arr {
    u_int v;
    const char *s;
};

static const struct arr str[] = {
    { v0, "zero"  },
    { v1, "one"   },
    { v2, "two"   },
    { v3, "three" },
    { 0, NULL     }
};
```

I have the following Rust code already done, but I can't figure out the best way to create an array of structs like the C code does.

```
static v0: u8 = 0;
static v1: u8 = 1;
static v2: u8 = 2;
static v3: u8 = 3;

struct arr {
    v: u8,
    s: &'static str,
}
```

I have tried the following code, but to no success:

```
static str: [arr; 4] = [
    {
        v: v0,
        s:"zero",
    },
    {
        v: v1,
        s:"one",
    },
    {
        v: v2,
        s:"two",
    },
    {
        v: v3,
        s:"three",
    },
];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360993/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-a-fixed-length-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your attempt was almost correct except you need to write out struct constructor with the name (no shortcut in Rust)

Note also that Rust has `const` in addition to `static`. (`const` in Rust is roughly equivalent to `const static` in C)

Playpen: http://is.gd/tPRVq4

```rust
const v0: i8 = 0;
const v1: i8 = 1;
const v2: i8 = 2;
const v3: i8 = 3;

struct Arr {
    v: i8,
    s: &'static str,
}

const str: [Arr; 4] = [
    Arr {
        v: v0,
        s:"zero",
    },
    Arr {
        v: v1,
        s:"one",
    },
    Arr {
        v: v2,
        s:"two",
    },
    Arr {
        v: v3,
        s:"three",
    },
];

fn main() {
    println!("{}", str[2].v);
}
```

Comment: You should also note that it's customary to start type names in uppercase.

Comment: @llogiq: I'll edit the code at least, the remark itself would be better as a comment on the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. rustc would have warned you if you were bothered to actually compile this code.  Also `const` item `str` should also be changed to `STR`, again according to rustc lint messages.