# Is it possible to declare an immutable Array and assign value to its elements separately in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization

I want to declare an Array and want to initialize it like this
  (maybe it is not good in real development, but I just want to figure it out)

the key point is that: 1. `h` is immutable  2. assign(also initialize) `h[0]` `h[1]` and `h[2]` separately.

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use rand::Rng; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    loop {
        let h: [u32; 3];
        h[0] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
        h[1] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
        h[2] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
        println!("{:?}", h);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
    }
}
```

but the compiler says that

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `h`
  --> src\main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         h[0] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
   |         ^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `h`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

of course `h` is uninitialized here, so what could I do?
or it is impossible to do such a thing

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=def7c91bd7335dbfe36e01c4f28b5984

Comment: Also see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-array-type

Comment: @hellow I didnt describe the problem well. but what if I want to initialize the elements of the array separately?

Comment: @Seact please do a [mcve] that describe better your problem so.

Comment: @Seact that's covered by multiple of the answers in [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360993/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-a-fixed-length-array).