# Array of enum with a possible variant containing reference

Tags: arrays, enums, rust

I tried coding the paper game of battleships, where a battlefield is an enum array. I couldn't find a way to initialize the array.

```rust
enum Tile {
    Water,
    Debris,
    Ship(Rc<Ship>),
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = [[Tile::Water; 10]; 10]; //Tile::Water doesn't implement Copy (the compiler is dumb)
    let mut b: [[Tile; 10]; 10];
    for i in 1..10 {
        for j in 1..10 {
            b[i][j] = Tile::Water;
        }
    } //use of possibly uninitialized b (I'm trying to initialize it)
}
```

How can this be done? I am **not** looking for another solution for the game, it is just an example here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388285/is-there-a-more-idiomatic-way-to-initialize-an-array-with-random-numbers-than-a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360993/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-a-fixed-length-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360993/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-a-fixed-length-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143009/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-immutable-array-and-assign-value-to-its-elements-se

Comment: *"the compiler is dumb"* nah.. it's not. It has valid reasons to not let that happen.

Comment: @hellow Two of those links are to the same question.

Comment: @hellow No, the compiler is truly dumb in this case. It has no good reason to not allow `[Tile::Water; 10]` and in fact it should eventually be allowed (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49147).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
enum Tile {
    Water,
    Debris,
    Ship(Rc<Ship>),
}

impl Default for Tile {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Tile::Water
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b: [[Tile; 10]; 10] = Default::default();
}
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the suggested duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656387/initialize-a-large-fixed-size-array-with-non-copy-types

Comment: @hellow The suggested question asks for non-Copy types generally. Non-Copy types usually have a good reason not to be copied "as-is" but an enum with only some variants which hold a reference is a specific case where, in many cases, copying is safe. That is not to say such enums should implement Copy. The compiler does not analyze, whether the value in question can be safely copied and straight out assumes it cannot. I asked for a work-around in this specific case.