# Singly-Linked List in Rust

Tags: linked-list, rust

I've been trying to teach myself some Rust lately and wanted to practice a bit by implementing a simple linked list. I took some inspiration from the Rust library's linked list and tried to replicate the parts I already understood. Also I decided to make it singly-linked for now.

```
struct Node<T> {
    element: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(element: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            element: element,
            next: None,
        }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, element: Box<Node<T>>) {
        self.next = Some(element);
    }
}

pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    tail: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    len: u32,
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        head: None,
        tail: None,
        len: 0,
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, element: T) {
        let node: Box<Node<T>> = Box::new(Node::new(element));

        match self.tail {
            None => self.head = Some(node),
            Some(mut ref tail) => tail.append(node),
        }
        self.tail = Some(node);
        self.len += 1;
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        //not implemented
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: u32) -> Option<T> {
        //not implemented
    }
}
```

This is what I've got so far; from what I understand, the problem with this code is that the `Box` can not have more than one reference to it in order to preserve memory safety.

So when I set the list head to node in

```
None => self.head = Some(node),
```

I can't then go ahead and set

```
self.tail = Some(node);
```

later, am I correct so far in my understanding? What would be the correct way to do this? Do I have to use `Shared` like in the library or is there a way in which the `Box` or some other type can be utilized?

Comment: [obligatory reference (Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists)](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/)

Comment: Note that the traditional singly-linked (Cons List) does not memorize the `tail`. It's a way to allow appending in O(1), but is not necessary.

Comment: @Oliver can you please accept Ijedrzs answer if it answers your question? Else please state what's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you are attempting to use a value (`node`) after having moved it; since `Box<Node<T>>` does not implement `Copy`, when you use it in the `match` expression:

```
match self.tail {
    None => self.head = Some(node),
    Some(ref mut tail) => tail.append(node),
}
```

`node` is moved either to `self.head` or to `self.tail` and can no longer be used later. Other than reading the obligatory [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/) to see the different ways in which you can implement linked lists in Rust, I suggest that you first do some more research in the field of Rust's basic concepts, especially:

- [Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html)
- [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html)
- [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-exactly)

Answer (score 3):

You can go with something simpler than that, only using your nodes

```
use std::fmt;

struct Payload {
  id: i32,
  value: i32,
}

impl fmt::Display for Payload {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.id, self.value)
    }
}

struct Node<T> {
    element: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> where T: std::fmt::Display{
    fn new(element: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            element: element,
            next: None,
        }
    }

    fn append(&mut self, element: T) {
        match &mut self.next {
            None => {let n = Node {
                        element: element,
                        next: None,
                    };
                    self.next = Some(Box::new(n));
            },
            Some(ref mut x) => x.append(element),
        }
    }

    fn list(& self) {
        println!("{}", self.element);
        match &self.next {
            None => {},
            Some(x) => x.list(),
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
  let mut h = Node::new(Payload {id:1, value:1});
  h.append(Payload {id:2, value:2});
  h.append(Payload {id:3, value:3});
  h.append(Payload {id:4, value:4});
  h.append(Payload {id:5, value:5});
  h.list();
  h.append(Payload {id:6, value:6});
  h.list();
}
```

Comment: So it's a recursive `append`, it's non-performant

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin will it be better if we just iterate the elements and do it, instead of recursion?