# Delete a node in singly linked list in Rust

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, rust

I am new to Rust and want to write linked list in Rust to have fun. I am confused about how to delete a node in the linked list. Here is my simple code.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node{
    v: usize,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

struct LinkedList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl LinkedList {
    fn remove(&mut self, v: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        let mut current_node: &mut Option<Box<Node>> = &mut self.head;
        loop {
           match current_node {
                None => break,
                Some(node) => {
                    if node.v == v {
                        // current_node = what? 
                        // ???????????????
                        break;
                    } else {
                        current_node = &mut node.next;
                    }
                },
            };
        }

        match current_node.take().map(|x| *x) {
            Some(node) => {
                *current_node = node.next;
                return Some(node.v)
            },
            None => None,
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e38a9006fb166fb10ba30cc0cda0b94). I am using the nightly version and `edition = 2018`. In the loop, I try to find the node whose next node contains the value that I search for. However, I am confused about what to write in the ?? position.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but highly (!!!) related! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653148/singly-linked-list-in-rust

Comment: Btw, you cannot modify `current_node` in that context, because it is currently borrowed, so this approach won't work.

Comment: @hellow Thanks. I realized this problem and read the link you attached. However I still do not know how to fix it 0.0

Comment: I hope you also read the provided link in the answer http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/third.html
This it **the** ultimate reference for linked lists in rust.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't really code that can go in that space to fix it; you'll need to make some bigger changes.

One of the problems is that you have mutably borrowed the current node in `current_node`, but then need to mutate it while that reference still exists.

Making use of non-lexical lifetimes in Edition 2018, you can do:

```
impl LinkedList {
    fn remove(&mut self, v: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        let mut current = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match current {
                None => return None,
                Some(node) if node.v == v => {
                    *current = node.next.take();
                    return Some(v);
                },
                Some(node) => {
                    current = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow, using the match guard `if node.v == v` to make two match arms, instead of using an `if` condition inside one match arm, lets the borrower checker deduce that this is safe. I'm not sure why the `if` statement inside the match arm isn't allowed - there are some of the [opinion that this could be a bug](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44710851#44710851).

Comment: You have no idea how much I struggled with this until I happened upon your answer.

Answer (score 0):

inspire by above answer, my solution is:

```
fn removeKFromList(mut head: ListNode<i32>, k: i32) -> ListNode<i32> {
  if head.is_none() {
        return None;
  }

  let mut current = &mut head;
  loop {
      match current {
          None => break,
          Some(node) if node.value == k => {
              *current = node.next.take();
          },
          Some(node) => {
              current = &mut node.next;
          }
      }
  }
  return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, if you have generic List, which accepts arbitrary type of content type `T` and returns deleted content to caller:

```
impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn remove_f<F: Fn(&T) -> bool>(&mut self, comparator: F) -> Option<T> {
        let mut curr_link = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match curr_link {
                None => return None,
                Some(node_ref) if comparator(&node_ref.elem) => {
                    let node = curr_link.take().unwrap();
                    *curr_link = node.next;
                    return Some(node.elem);
                },
                Some(node) => curr_link = &mut node.next,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Use example, assume `T = &str` and list contains element with value `"1"` and no element with value `"smth"`:

```
assert_eq!(list.remove_f(|node| "1".eq(node.deref())), Some("1"));
assert_eq!(list.remove_f(|node| "smth".eq(node.deref())), None);
```