# References in linked list implementation

Tags: rust

I am trying to do the [Simple Linked List](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/1c2c399a4fcc4d74a749c5f6c8af0a3d) Exercism problem, but I am stuck implementing the `pop()` method. The errors I get are not very clear to me; I'm not quite used to Rust's way of thinking, I guess.

Also, because of the compiler suggestions, I added a bunch of `as_ref()` that I don't really understand.

I am interested in knowing why my way of doing things doesn't work more than the solution.

```
pub struct SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, _element: T) {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        // Recursive function to return the before last element of the list
        fn get_before_last<'a, T>(
            prev: &'a Box<Node<T>>,
            current: &'a Box<Node<T>>,
        ) -> &'a Box<Node<T>> {
            match &current.next {
                Some(next_node) => get_before_last(&current, &next_node),
                None => &prev,
            }
        }

        // Check if the head is None
        match &self.head {
            None => return None,
            _ => (),
        };

        let before_last = &mut match &self.head {
            // Beginning of the recursion
            Some(node) => get_before_last(&node, node.next.as_ref().unwrap()),
            None => self.head.as_ref().unwrap(),
        };

        let to_pop = before_last.next.as_ref();
        before_last.next = None;

        Some(to_pop.unwrap().data)
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `before_last.next` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:48:9
   |
48 |         before_last.next = None;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:50:14
   |
50 |         Some(to_pop.unwrap().data)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Comment: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) is *strongly* recommended reading for anyone writing data structures in Rust, or using Rust at all, really.

Comment: [Cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338659/155423); [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423); [`Option::is_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none); [What would be a better way to implement .pop() in my single linked list in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55062035/155423)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not suited for general feedback on your code, but rather for specific problems. You are encouraged to post to [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) if you want broad feedback on your working code.

Comment: @Shepmaster: My question was about the bug I got. I just wanted people to not hesitate to correct anything else. Thank you for the links also. Since I don't understand well my issues, it's hard to look for related ones. I'll definitely check these out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `before_last` is not mutable. In fact it's a `&mut &'a Box<Node>`. For this reason you cannot assign anything to the node because it's a mutable reference to an immutable one.

The best suggestion I can give you is to rethink the implementation. Instead of pushing and popping to the end of the chain, you can do so on the front.
Create a new boxed node, remove the head and put it in the new node's next field. Then the new node becomes the head.

This way you have a LIFO list and you don't have to traverse the whole list to push & pop, so it's also more efficient. Pushing to the front also reduces the amount of code required.

My solution is [available on Exercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/rust/exercises/simple-linked-list/solutions/63645decb460490fb3fa6a3ef8e5e840).

Comment: Oh you're totally right, I should put it in the front... But just for the sake of knowing, let's say I wanted to always put it at the end, would my code be fixable? Doing `let before_last = &mut match &mut self.head` does not work, so I'm not sure how to make `before_last` a mutable reference

Comment: @Naktor You would need to have the function get_before_last to take mutable references (`&'a mut Box<Node<T>>`). The problem is that you would end up with a double `mut` borrow, which is not allowed in safe rust. I have yet to see a solution using this approach that doesn't use `unsafe`.