# What are the differences when I delete a specified value in a singly linked list in rust?

Tags: rust, singly-linked-list

I am new to Rust and want to write linked list in Rust. However, I am confused about some parts of the code. Here is my code：

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
  #[inline]
  fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      next: None,
      val
    }
  }
}
pub fn delete_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, val: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut res =  head;
    let mut head = & mut res;
    while let Some(node) = head {
        if node.val != val {
            // This works
            head = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
            // but it will report an error at （\*head = node.next.take();）：cannot assign to \*head because it is borrowed \*head is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
            // head = &mut node.next;
        } else {
            *head = node.next.take();
            break;
        }
    }
    res
}
```

When I use

`head = &mut node.next;`
the program cannot compile.
`\*head = node.next.take();`
This place reports an error：
`cannot assign to \*head because it is borrowed \*head is assigned to here but it was already borrowed`
In my understanding, node.next and head.as_mut().unwrap().next should be equivalent, but why does the former result in an error?
can you help me?

I found a similar issue, but it didn't solve my confusion
[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554862/delete-a-node-in-singly-linked-list-in-rust)
In the answer to this question, one response states: "Somehow, using the match guard if node.v == v to create two match arms, rather than utilizing an if condition within one match arm, allows the borrow checker to deduce that this is safe. I'm not certain why an if statement inside the match arm isn't permitted." I suspect it may be for the same reason as mine, but I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: "I am new to Rust and want to write linked list in Rust." - That's probably not the best way to start with Rust.

Comment: Writing a linked list is not a good exercise for learning Rust. If you must, make sure to read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: Classic Polonius problem.