# Calculating the longest array of Chars in Vector

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes `char_vec: &Vec<Chars>` as an argument. I know that the length of each `Chars` may be different - I want to get the length of the longest one. I'm trying to do it with a following code:

```rust
let longest = char_vec.iter().map(|x| x.count()).max().unwrap_or(0);
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following error:

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*x` which is behind a shared reference
  --> C:\Rust\playground\src\lib.rs:62:43
   |
62 |     let longest = char_vec.iter().map(|x| x.count()).max().unwrap_or(0);
   |                                           ^ move occurs because `*x` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't really understand how to execute the `count()` method here. The `Chars` struct seems to not implement a common traits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few parts you need to understand to understand why you get this error here.

First of all, Rust is all about [ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) of values and by default has [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust) instead of copy semantics as you're probably used to from other programming languages.

> The Chars struct seems to not implement a common traits?

When a struct implements the `Copy` trait, then it works using copy semantics. But `Chars` does not implement the `Copy` trait, as the error message says. This is of course on purpose and not a flaw or bug in the standard library.

A [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) object is an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) over the chars in a string slice. The [`count` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) of an `Iterator` takes `self` (the value, not a reference `&self`) as a parameter, which means it takes ownership of the iterator that you call it on. The API documentation also says this:

> *Consumes the iterator*, counting the number of iterations and returning it.

But note that you have a `Vec<Chars>`, so you have a `Vec` that owns the `Chars` objects. You cannot call `count()` on the `Chars` object owned by the `Vec`, because the `count()` function needs to take over ownership and it can't because the `Vec` already owns it.

`Chars` does not implement the `Copy` trait, but it does implement `Clone`, so one thing you can do is to explicitly create a copy of the `Chars` by calling `Clone` on it:

```
let longest = char_vec.iter().map(|x| x.clone().count()).max().unwrap_or(0);
                                       ^^^^^^^^ Make an explicit clone of the Chars here
```

You can then call `count()` on the clone.

Comment: Out of interest, wouldn't `into_iter()` also work, except for it consuming `char_vec` by moving it, making it unavailable afterwards?

Comment: @Jason Yes, that would also work, but indeed `char_vec` would then be unavailable afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. I still have trouble with understanding some of the concepts in rust, but I'm getting better.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) do implement [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait (and so it can use its methods). The problem here that `count` accepts `self` by-value, i.e. has signature `Iterator::count(self) -> usize`. On the other side, [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) you've called iterates over references, i.e. over `&Chars` rather than `Chars`. So you need to convert an item to the owned one, i.e.:

```rust
use std::iter::Iterator;
let longest = v.iter().cloned().map(Iterator::count).max().unwrap_or(0);

// you may also do the same with each item explicitly:
let longest = v.iter().map(|x| x.clone().count()).max().unwrap_or(0);
```

Keep in mind that cloning there is a fairly cheap operation (as well as with the most of the other iterators). `Chars` iterator is just a pair of pointers. So the copying performed on this pair of integer values rather than a whole underlying string.

Comment: Should be noted that cloning a Chars is essentially free, it just duplicates the underlying `slice::Iter` which is two pointers (the current position in the string, and the end pointer).

Comment: That's interesting @Masklinn. I assumed `Clone` would be an expensive operation by default, but it's inexpensive due to it only cloning the following `struct` https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#3451-3457 with its `ptr` and `end` field?

Comment: Yes. `Clone` really means "arbitrary operations", it doesn't necessarily mean expensive e.g. if you `derive(Copy, Clone)` `Clone` is just an alias for `Copy` which is extremely cheap.

Comment: @Masklinn added a note regarding the cheapness, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers explain, the `count` method consumes the caller object. However, `Chars` is owned by the parent vector and not a `Copy`. Another solution is to use `iter_mut` to iterate the vector so as to let the vector give up the ownership. The side effect is the vector cannot be used afterward.

```
let mut char_vec = vec!["abc".chars(), "1234567890".chars(), "de".chars()];
    
let longest = char_vec.iter_mut().map(|x| x.count()).max().unwrap_or(0);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b95b65159c95475993f756f2ac2607c7)