# Does ownership transfer of a vector change its memory location in Rust?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code snippet:

```rust
fn main() {   
    let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("The address of vector v1 is {:p}", &v1);
    let v2 = v1;
    println!("The address of vector v2 is {:p}", &v2);
    v1 = v2;
    println!("The address of vector v1 is {:p}", &v1);
}
```

and the output

```
The address of vector v1 is 0x7fff253de570
The address of vector v2 is 0x7fff253de5e0
The address of vector v1 is 0x7fff253de570
```

Why does the value of `v1` and `v2` not the same?

1. First, Doesn't `&v2` really mean the address of vector `vec![1,2,3]` as declared in line #2?
2. If the value of `v1` is *copied* to `v2` then, should not the vector have a copy trait?
3. If the value of `v1` is moved to a new memory location which is identified by `v2`, why is it at all required, why doesn't the `v2` simply point to the memory location of `v1`, because the ownership is already transferred to `v2`, and `v1` is pretty much useless until I assign it back (in short, if it is a memory copy, why does the ownership transfer require a `memcpy`?)
4. When `v1` is assigned to `v2` again, how did I get the same address location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust)

Comment: Extract of one of the answers of the linked QA: **"Conceptually, moving something doesn't need to do anything"**

Comment: @DenysSéguret The answers in it do *partially* answer the question, they do not answer specifically about addresses, for example question 1 isn't answered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the address of the data and the address of the variable. In the beginning, your memory looks something like this:

```
    Stack               Heap
+----+------+---+       +---+---+---+
|    | len  | 3 |   +-->| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| v1 +------+---+   |   +---+---+---+
|    | data     |---+
+----+------+---+
|    | len  | _ |
| v2 +------+---+
|    | data     |
+----+----------+
```

After you do `let v2 = v1`, it looks like this:

```
    Stack               Heap
+----+------+---+       +---+---+---+
|    | len  | _ |   +-->| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| v1 +------+---+   |   +---+---+---+
|    | data     |   |
+----+------+---+   |
|    | len  | 3 |   |
| v2 +------+---+   |
|    | data     |---+
+----+----------+
```

Note that the locations of `v1` and `v2` have not changed, and neither has the location of the data on the heap, but the values of the *fields* of `v1` have been moved into `v2`. At that point, the values of the fields of `v1` are invalid.

Then when you do `v1 = v2`, you go back to the first configuration.

OTOH your `println` statements print the address of the variables `v1` and `v2` on the stack.

Note that if you print `&v1[0]` (resp. `&v2[0]`), you will get the address of the data on the heap and see that it doesn't change ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17541bbc6d33f669468e2059883cac09))

Comment: So, that means the address of the heap is actually *copied* (`memcpy`) to `v2.data` when I say `v2=v1`, right?

Comment: Also, you said to use `&v1[0]` to get the address of the data in the vector, how do we do it for user-defined `struct`?

Comment: For completeness, a vector also has a capacity (which is not really relevant here).

Comment: @JavaTechnical Moving a vector _might_ copy its metadata (i.e. length, capacity, data pointer). The compiler is free to eliminate the copy if it can proof it's not needed. The actual data is never copied.

Comment: If your user-definied struct allocates memory on the heap, it depends on the public interface of your struct how to get the address of that memory. It might not be exposed at all.

Comment: @SvenMarnach ok, since the vector has implemented an index trait and has put the data at the 0th index, we get the address of the data on the heap. For custom structs, either we would need to implement a method or follow the vector approach, right?

Comment: @Jmb in order to get the address of the vec('s buffer) you can also "cast" it to a slice using `&*` (or `.as_slice()`, or `&[..]`). rather than try to access a first element it may or may not have.

Comment: From a low-level (HW) standpoint, there is no difference between a copy and a move. They both translate to the same assembly involving a `memcpy` (which may be optimized away if the compiler can prove that it's not needed). The difference is that in the case of a "move", the compiler considers that the source data is no longer valid, whereas for a "copy" both source and destination are valid afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the value of `v1` and `v2` not the same?

Why would it be the same? They are different variables in the stack.

What is the same is the storage in the heap.

> 1. First, Doesn't `&v2` really mean the address of vector `vec![1,2,3]` as declared in line #2?

No, it means borrowing `v2`. What you see is `{:p}` being implemented for references which prints their address.

> 2. If the value of `v1` is *copied* to `v2` then, should not the vector have a copy trait?

No, in most cases you do not want to allocate memory in the heap and copy it.

> 3. If the value of `v1` is moved to a new memory location which is identified by `v2`, why is it at all required, why doesn't the `v2` simply point to the memory location of `v1`, because the ownership is already transferred to `v2`, and `v1` is pretty much useless until I assign it back (in short, if it is a memory copy, why does the ownership transfer require a `memcpy`?)

That is what actually occurs. It is a move, so only the bits of the vectors are copied, not the contents in the heap.

> 4. When `v1` is assigned to `v2` again, how did I get the same address location?

Why would it be different? It is still the same palce in the stack.

Answer (score -3):

1. `&v2` is a reference to `v2`, not the address of `v2`.
2. `v2` is not a copy of `v1`, it is a "move", but since it is the same scope, nothing really happens.
3. `v1` is now the moved value of `v2`, again same scope, so the same address can be reused.
4. Address is not the same thing as a variable.