# How do I reference a global variable in multiple closures without getting "error[E0382]: use of moved value"?

Tags: rust

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let pos = Position { x: 4, y: 5 };

    let foo1 = move || {
        println!("{:?}", pos);
    };

    let foo2 = move || {
        println!("{:?}", pos);
    };

    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

I got the error message:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `pos`
  --> src/main.rs:14:16
   |
8  |     let pos = Position { x: 4, y: 5 };
   |         --- move occurs because `pos` has type `Position`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
9  | 
10 |     let foo1 = move || {
   |                ------- value moved into closure here
11 |         println!("{:?}", pos);
   |                          --- variable moved due to use in closure
...
14 |     let foo2 = move || {
   |                ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
15 |         println!("{:?}", pos);
   |                          --- use occurs due to use in closure
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust)

Comment: That's not a global value, it's just a regular variable. For *this specific case*, you could choose to [make it a constant](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b42b48e79f0b81b558a4727674a6e46)

Answer (score 0):

After your declaration of `foo1` the variable `pos` no longer belongs to main, but has been moved into the `foo1` closure.

How to resolve this depends on what you want to achieve.
You could implement the `Clone` trait for your `Position` struct via `#[derive(Debug, Clone)]`, create a clone for `foo1` and use the cloned value instead:

````
```
let pos_foo1 = pos.clone();
let foo1 = move ||{
    println!("{:?}", pos_foo1);
};
```
````

Comment: thank your answers, what if I want to use the same instance to share state in this two closure functions?

Comment: Then you need a way to synchronize access to the data. You could do that with a [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), but it depends on your use case.