# immutable HashMap after filling it

Tags: rust

Here is a piece of code that counts the frequency of words in a sentence.
I'm wondering if the `HashMap` can be set as immutable after counting the items.

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::new();
for word in s.split_whitespace() {
    *map.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
// after the for loop make map immutable
```

I'm aware of the crate `Counter` with the `collect` API but I'd prefer to do it without crates.

I would also prefer a solution that doesn't use functions or closures.

Comment: Relevant questions: [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust), [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Aleksander's answer, you can use `Iterator::fold()` to avoid making it mutable in the first place:

```
let map = s.split_whitespace().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut map, word| {
    *map.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
    map
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mutable variable and want to make it immutable later you can do simple *shadowing*:

```rust
// x is mut
let mut x = ...;

// do stuff with mut x

// now x is no longer mutable
let x = x;
```

Comment: However note that there is no way to make it _truly_ immutable: it is always possible to shadow it back to be mutable: `let mut x = x;`

Comment: @Jmb isn't that the same for every variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make data truly unchangeable, e.g. to be sure it stays valid in between function calls, you can wrap the value in a newtype which implements the Deref-Trait. [see playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f260383403ce9f592596ed4a93c26b6)

Now you can pass it around in your Application and rely, that all code which can change the inner value must be in the `sealed` module. If you find this interesting, you might want to check out my experimental crate [sealedstruct](https://github.com/mineichen/sealedstruct) for inspiration to generate boilerplate. Be aware that it is neither published nor well documented yet.