# What is the difference between Copy and Clone?

Tags: rust

[This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23790) seems to imply it's just an implementation detail (`memcpy` vs ???), but I can't find any explicit description of the differences.

Comment: Rust's source code has [relevant explanation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2e6eaceedeeda764056eb0e2134735793533770d/src/libcore/marker.rs#L272)

Comment: @duan here those comments are on the official docs site: [What is the difference between `Copy` and `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone) and more on the very top of the docs page for [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`Clone` is designed for arbitrary duplications: a `Clone` implementation for a type `T` can do arbitrarily complicated operations required to create a new `T`. It is a normal trait (other than being in the prelude), and so requires being used like a normal trait, with method calls, etc.

The `Copy` trait represents values that can be safely duplicated via `memcpy`: things like reassignments and passing an argument by-value to a function are always `memcpy`s, and so for `Copy` types, the compiler understands that it doesn't need to consider those [a move](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24253344/1256624).

Comment: Can I understand as `Clone` is a deep-copy, and `Copy` is shadow-copy?

Comment: `Clone` opens the *possibility* that the type might do either a deep or shallow copy: "arbitrarily complicated".

Comment: Fascinating, I thought `Copy` was just about allowing to make the `Clone` trait implicit. I'll leave here the reference as I'm probably not the only one puzzled.
That exact question is answered in the manual now ( possibly not at the time of this question ): "Copies happen implicitly, for example as part of an assignment y = x. The behavior of Copy is not overloadable; it is always a simple bit-wise copy." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone

Answer (score 153):

The main difference is that cloning is explicit. Implicit notation means move for a non-`Copy` type.

```
// u8 implements Copy
let x: u8 = 123;
let y = x;
// x can still be used
println!("x={}, y={}", x, y);

// Vec<u8> implements Clone, but not Copy
let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
let w = v.clone();
//let w = v // This would *move* the value, rendering v unusable.
```

By the way, every `Copy` type is also required to be `Clone`. However, they are not required to do the same thing! For your own types, `.clone()` can be an arbitrary method of your choice, whereas implicit copying will always trigger a `memcpy`, not the `clone(&self)` implementation.

Comment: Cool! This clears up a secondary question I had regarding whether the Clone trait provides implicit copying. Turns out that question and this one were more related than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: In your first example, suppose you wanted `y` to get a moved `x`, not a copy of it, like with your last commented out example `w = v`. How would you specify that?

Comment: You can't, and you don't, because `Copy` is meant to be implemented for "cheap" types, such as `u8` in the example. If you write a quite heavyweight type, for which you think a move is more efficient than a copy, make it _not_ impl `Copy`. Note that in the u8 case, you cannot possibly be more efficient with a move, since under the hood it would probably at least entail a pointer copy -- which is already as expensive as a u8 copy, so why bother.

Comment: Does this mean that the presence of the `Copy` trait has an impact on the implicit lifetime scopes of variables?  If so I think that's noteworthy.

Answer (score 56):

As already covered by other answers:

- `Copy` is implicit, inexpensive, and cannot be re-implemented (memcpy).
- `Clone` is explicit, may be expensive, and may be re-implemented arbitrarily.

What is sometimes missing in the discussion of `Copy` vs `Clone` is that it also affects how the compiler uses moves vs automatic copies. For instance:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct PointCloneAndCopy {
    pub x: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct PointCloneOnly {
    pub x: f64,
}

fn test_copy_and_clone() {
    let p1 = PointCloneAndCopy { x: 0. };
    let p2 = p1; // because type has `Copy`, it gets copied automatically.
    println!("{:?} {:?}", p1, p2);
}

fn test_clone_only() {
    let p1 = PointCloneOnly { x: 0. };
    let p2 = p1; // because type has no `Copy`, this is a move instead.
    println!("{:?} {:?}", p1, p2);
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e662d436aca8406a47a2b88e9438a5b5))

The first example (`PointCloneAndCopy`) works fine here because of the implicit copy, but the second example (`PointCloneOnly`) would error with a use after move:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `p1`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:27
   |
18 |     let p1 = PointCloneOnly { x: 0. };
   |         -- move occurs because `p1` has type `PointCloneOnly`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
19 |     let p2 = p1;
   |              -- value moved here
20 |     println!("{:?} {:?}", p1, p2);
   |                           ^^ value borrowed here after move
```

To avoid the implicit move, we could explicitly call `let p2 = p1.clone();`.

This may raise the question of [how to force a move of a type which implements the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31168589/1804173).

*Short answer: You can't / doesn't make sense.*

Comment: Clone can be cheaper, no? when it is a shallow copy.

Comment: @jangorecki I'm not sure. My understanding is that `Copy` simply does a memcpy of the raw struct in memory. This is as "shallow" as it can get, and should not be confused with "deep copying". The cheapest possible `Clone` that doesn't lose information would basically have to emulate a memcpy. Perhaps a `Clone` can be cheaper e.g. if it doesn't copy all fields though.

Answer (score 11):

As written [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone).

> Copies happen implicitly, for example as part of an assignment `y = x`. The behavior of `Copy` is not overloadable; it is always a simple bit-wise copy.

> Cloning is an explicit action, `x.clone()`. The implementation of `Clone` can provide any type-specific behavior necessary to duplicate values safely. For example, the implementation of `Clone` for `String` needs to copy the pointed-to string buffer in the heap. A simple bitwise copy of `String` values would merely copy the pointer, leading to a double free down the line. For this reason, `String` is `Clone` but not `Copy`.

> `Clone` is a supertrait of `Copy`, so everything which is `Copy` must also implement `Clone`. If a type is `Copy` then its `Clone` implementation only needs to return `*self`

Answer (score 2):

I found this explanation very helpful:

In Rust, some simple types are “implicitly copyable” and when you assign them or pass them as arguments, the receiver will get a copy, leaving the original value in place. For other types, copies must be made explicitly, by implementing the `Clone` trait and calling the `clone()` method.

The `Clone` trait defines the ability to explicitly create a deep copy of an object T. When we call `Clone` for type T, it does all the arbitrarily complicated operations required to create a new T.

The `Copy` trait in rust defines the ability to implicitly copy an object. The behavior `Copy` is not overloadable. It is always a simple bitwise copy. This is available for the types that have a fixed size and are stored entirely on the stack.

Reference: https://intmain.co/difference-between-copy-and-clone-trait-in-rust

Comment: "The `Clone` trait defines the ability to explicitly create a deep copy". No, the copy is arbitrary, hence not necessarily deeply. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the intention is all your need

- both can be used to avoid borrow and lifetime annotation or smart pointer
- copy means copy semantics here, or means the value is going to be treated like in Java or JS language, this implies the value is somehow primitive or cheap to copy
- clone let you decide how deep the duplication is enough and you have to explicitly write `.clone`, which means it is already handled