# How to clone last element from vector?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write code that gets the last element of some vector and do different actions (including mutation of the vector) depending on that element.

I tried like this:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
enum ParseItem {
    Start,
    End,
}

let mut item_vec = vec![ParseItem::End];
loop {
    let last_item = *item_vec.last().clone().unwrap();
    match last_item {
        ParseItem::End => item_vec.push(ParseItem::Start),
        _ => break,
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

> error: cannot move out of borrowed content
>   let last_item = *item_vec.last().clone().unwrap();

I thought by cloning `item_vec.last()`, the problems with ownership would be solved, but it seems not.

If I try the same thing with a vector of integers like this:

```
let mut int_vec = vec![0];
loop {
    let last_int = *int_vec.last().clone().unwrap();
    match last_int {
        0 => int_vec.push(1),
        _ => break,
    }
}
```

the compiler doesn't complain about borrowing.

Why does my code fails to compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`item_vec.last()` is an `Option<&T>`.

`item_vec.last().clone()` is another `Option<&T>`. This actually performs a *shallow* copy of the reference. This means you haven't actually fixed anything!

Intuitively, this makes sense - cloning a pointer can return a value type to store directly on the stack, but a clone of an `Option<&T>` *can't* clone the `T` because it has nowhere to put it.

This works because an `Option<T>` actually calls `clone` on an `&T`, so `Option<&T>` calls `clone` on an `&&T`, which means the `&self` parameter in the trait resolves to `self = &T`. This means we use [the `impl` of `Clone` for `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#54-58):

```
impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Clone for &'a T {
    /// Returns a shallow copy of the reference.
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> &'a T { *self }
}
```

`*item_vec.last().clone().unwrap()` thus is still a borrow of the vector.

One can fix this in two basic ways. One is to use [`Option`'s `cloned` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned), which clones the inner reference away:

```
item_vec.last().cloned().unwrap()
```

[This is implemented as a `map` on the internal data:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#706-708)

```
impl<'a, T: Clone> Option<&'a T> {
    /// Maps an Option<&T> to an Option<T> by cloning the contents of the Option.
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub fn cloned(self) -> Option<T> {
        self.map(|t| t.clone())
    }
}
```

The other option is to `unwrap` and only *then* `clone` the reference, to get a value out:

```
item_vec.last().unwrap().clone()
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! But I still have some questions. 1. first solution with cloned() works well, but second solution still has same error. Why does this happens? 2. Why does the integer version of code works without all these corrections?

Comment: @Yang The second solution accidentally had an extra "`*`"; try again to see if it works now. The integer version works because integers are `Copy`, which means assignment `let new = *ref` causes a copy, not a move. [I've talked more about moves vs. copies elsewhere.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31171431/1763356)