# Require generic type implements copy or clone | Vector of generics from fixed array of generics

Tags: generics, vector, rust, slice, lifetime

I am trying to implement a custom data structure in Rust that behaves like a Set in mathematics (supports Union, Intersection, Disjoint Comparison, etc.) I want the constructor (associated function new) to take a slice of generic type `T` and populate a Vector of type `T`.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct CustomSet<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> CustomSet<T> {
    pub fn new(input: &[T]) -> Self {
       let mut elements = Vec::new();
       for elm in input {
           elements.push(*elm);
       }
       CustomSet {
           elements
       }
    }
}
```

This makes the compiler very upset, because `T` does not necessarily implement `Copy` (or `Clone` for that matter). I can't manually implement `Copy` or `Clone` on `T` because I have no idea what `T` is. I'd prefer not to use a `Vec<&T>` because I don't really want to manage lifetimes. I think the solution is to somehow require that `T` implement `Clone` or `Copy`, which is fine for my purposes, but I also don't know how to do that. Any and all advice on this matter is welcome.

Comment: Wow. You have the exact question I had. Thanks for saving me the trouble of asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Copy` constraint in generic impl:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct CustomSet<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: Copy> CustomSet<T> {
    pub fn new(input: &[T]) -> Self {
       CustomSet {
           elements: input.to_vec()
       }
    }
}
```

`Clone` constraint in generic impl:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct CustomSet<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: Clone> CustomSet<T> {
    pub fn new(input: &[T]) -> Self {
       CustomSet {
           elements: input.to_vec()
       }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [*Trait Bound Syntax* in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bound-syntax)
- [What's the difference between Copy and Clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31012923/2766908)

Comment: 5 characters and my life is easy again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I solved my issue temporarily. But I don't understand the multiple impl statements for Clone and Copy, does it means that I should implement them separately and the main struct impl again? I'm a complete noob just trying to patch rust code for learning. I'm going to read the links now.

Comment: @Vignesh you don't need multiple impls, I only showed multiple impls since OP asked about them. Reading the _See also_ links at the bottom of my answer should answer any follow-up questions you have, otherwise feel welcome to post a new question on StackOverflow tagged with the "rust" tag.