# Is Clone for copying on the heap, while Copy for copying on the stack in Rust?

Tags: rust

As the title says, will I be correct to say that Clone for copying on the heap, while Copy for copying on the stack in Rust?

This is basically what this article [here](https://mirror.xyz/0xB38709B8198d147cc9Ff9C133838a044d78B064B/c_ZPbkCMKqJwSOeDRtleF6RSGwFeIiz4PIhcO3fHlCc) says, but I have doubts over its correctness.

Comment: Copy is a bitwise Copy. Clone is a method that could be implemented to do anything(well anything within the constraints of its type signature). Both can be used on both the stack and heap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Copy and Clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012923/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying vs cloning do not equate to stack vs heap. `Copy` and `Clone` are traits which are properties of the *type*, not properties on where the value lies. They are more closely tied with ownership than memory region.

Consider this example where integers are stored on the heap (via `Vec`) and I copy from one element to another. This uses `Copy` (because there is no explicit `.clone()`) and yet both the source and destination are on the heap:

```
let mut v = vec![0i32; 10];
v[0] = v[1];
```

Consider this example where a `RefCell` is stored on the stack, and uses `Clone` to get another of the same. Both elements are on the stack and yet I must use `.clone()` because `RefCell` does not implement `Copy`. A `RefCell` doesn't use any heap allocations either:

```
let rc1 = RefCell::new(...);
let rc2 = rc1.clone();
```

A type implementing `Copy` simply means that it can be bitwise-copied from one memory location to another and have both instances be equally valid.

What is important for comparing `Copy` and `Clone` is if there is additional meaning that needs to be applied when the type is created or destroyed beyond the in-place data it holds. Having ownership over heap-allocated memory *is* one of those cases, since you would need to de-allocate that memory when the owner is destroyed. Keeping additional book-keeping records, as a `RefCell` does would also disqualify it from implementing `Copy` since a simple bitwise-copy of the data would yield inconsistent or unusable results. Managing an external resource like an file handle is another case since you must coordinate with the OS to `open()` and `close()` the file explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for this! Helps clarify a lot of the confusion I was facing

Answer (score -1):

`Clone` trait provides `clone` method for copying. Stack or heap depends on implementation and type requirements. For example, if you’re cloning a `String`, copied value will be allocated in the heap. If you’re cloning a value of `u8` type, copied value will be allocated on the stack. `Copy` trait does exactly what the `Clone` trait does, but implicitly.

If every cloned value was allocated in the heap, we wouldn’t need allocators

Comment: if it was exactly the same, we wouldn't need both.

Comment: If we wouldn’t need both, they wouldn’t exist 

Comment: Copy tells compiler that value must not be invalidated while moving it. It just clones it instead.