# How to modify a R string in Rust and assign it to a new R variable and keep the original R string using extendr

Tags: r, rust, rextendr, extendr

For example, I want to change R string `s <- c("aaa", NA, "bbb")` to `s1 <- c("AAA", NA, "bbb")` and keep the original `s`. In the code below, I can make the changes and assign the new string to `s1`. However, `s` is also changed. I made a copy of s with `.clone()` in the Rust code. Why is `s` still changed?

```r
library(rextendr)

rust_source(code = '
#[extendr]
fn strings_elt(x: Strings) -> Strings {
    let mut y = x.clone();
    y.set_elt(0, "AAA".into());
    rprintln!("x is {:?} and y is {:?}", x, y);
    y
}
')

s <- c("aaa", NA, "bbb")
s1 <- strings_elt(s)
s1   # "AAA" NA    "bbb"
s    # "AAA" NA    "bbb", also changed
```

Comment: Without even looking at `rextendr` package, I strongly suspect you have not noticed some documentation on `Rust` functions which stress that the source object will be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A general note on cloning in Rust

In Rust the [`Clone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012923/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone) trait is,

> designed for arbitrary duplications: a `Clone` implementation for a type `T` can do arbitrarily complicated operations required to create a new `T`.

This means it might create a deep or shallow copy. However, with a Rust `String` or `Vec<String>`, it makes a deep copy:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Clone and then mutate a string
    let mut s: String = String::from("Initial value");
    let mut s_clone: String = s.clone();
    s_clone = String::from("New value");
    println!("s is: {s}\ns_clone is: {s_clone}");

    // Clone and then mutate a vector of strings
    let mut s_vec: Vec<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
    let mut s_vec_clone: Vec<String> = s_vec.clone();
    s_vec_clone[0] = "c".to_string();
    println!("s_vec is: {:?}\ns_clone is: {:?}", s_vec, s_vec_clone);
}
```

This returns:

```
s is: Initial value
s_clone is: New value
s_vec is: ["a", "b"]
s_clone is: ["c", "b"]
```

I would expect this behaviour as by-reference vs by-value is one of the key [differences between a `String` and `&str`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str).

### Cloning `Strings` in `extendr`

The [docs](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/extendr_api/wrapper/strings/struct.Strings.html#impl-Clone-for-Strings) for the `extendr_api::wrapper::strings::Strings` implementation of the `Clone` trait state,

> Returns a copy of the value.

As it does not specify deep or shallow, we might expect the same behaviour for `Strings` as either a `String` or a vector of `String`s. This would also be consistent with [`clone()`](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/201_caution_vector.html) in `Rcpp`.

Your example, however, demonstrates it is not a deep copy as modifying the copy also modifies the original.

`Strings` is a wrapper around the workhorse of `extendr`, i.e [`extendr_api::robj::Robj`](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/extendr_api/robj/struct.Robj.html), which itself is a

> wrapper for an R S-expression pointer (SEXP).

As a reminder [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs) says,

> What R users think of as variables or objects are symbols which are bound to a value. The value can be thought of as either a `SEXP` (a pointer), or the structure it points to, a `SEXPREC`

The `Clone` trait for `Robj` [calls](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/src/extendr_api/robj/mod.rs.html#115-119) `Robj::from_sexp(self.get())`, which in turn [calls](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/src/extendr_api/robj/mod.rs.html#133):

```rust
/// Access to a raw SEXP pointer can cause undefined behaviour and is not thread safe.
unsafe fn get(&self) -> SEXP;
```

i.e. it returns a pointer, rather than the object itself. The [docs](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/extendr_api/wrapper/strings/struct.Strings.html#method.duplicate) for the `duplicate()` method confirm this:

> Do a deep copy of this object. Note that clone() only adds a reference.

However, you'll note that `duplicate()` returns an object of type `Robj`. This seems a bit peculiar to me as I would expect a duplicate of a `Strings` object to return a `Strings` object. However, it is straightforward to use `Strings::try_from()` to coerce the `Robj` back to `Strings`, keeping in mind that this method returns a `Result<Strings>` so we need to unwrap it.

```r
rust_source(code = '
#[extendr]
fn strings_elt(x: Strings) -> Strings {
    let mut y = Strings::try_from(x.duplicate()).unwrap();
    y.set_elt(0, "AAA".into());
    rprintln!("x is {:?} and y is {:?}", x, y);
    y
}
')

s <- c("aaa", NA, "bbb")
s1 <- strings_elt(s)
s1 # "AAA" NA    "bbb"
s # "aaa" NA    "bbb"
```

We can see now that modifying the duplicate no longer changes the original.