# How do I implement one of the std::ops:{Add, Sub, Mul, Div} operators without moving out the the arguments?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a ray-tracer and I want to be able to subtract my 3D vectors:

```
use std::ops::Sub;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    pub v: [f64; 3],
}

impl Sub for Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;

    fn sub(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3 {
            v: [
                self.v[0] - other.v[0],
                self.v[1] - other.v[1],
                self.v[2] - other.v[2],
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work. However, when I try to use it:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Vec3 { v: [0., 0., 0.] };
    let y = Vec3 { v: [0., 0., 0.] };
    let a = x - y;
    let b = x - y;
}
```

I get complaints from the compiler:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:26:13
   |
25 |     let a = x - y;
   |             - value moved here
26 |     let b = x - y;
   |             ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `Vec3`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `y`
  --> src/main.rs:26:17
   |
25 |     let a = x - y;
   |                 - value moved here
26 |     let b = x - y;
   |                 ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `y` has type `Vec3`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I write the subtraction operator so that the code above works?

Please don't tell me I should an existing 3D math module. I'm sure there's something better, but I'm after learning how to do it myself to learn the language.

[How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005134) doesn't help as it requires specifying lifetimes for object which I'm not at yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005134/how-do-i-implement-the-add-trait-for-a-reference-to-a-struct)

Comment: @trentcl thanks!! Consider making this an answer. I'm still processing the other options, but since I don't know yet what a lifetime is, I'm having difficulty comparing them. Your suggestion fixes my issue, but I'm not sure the copy is the correct trade-off.

Comment: @Jeffrey The `Copy` marker permits to silently copy your struct when needed.

Comment: I don't think the last paragraph is a legitimate constraint to put on a question. Would you ask your driving teacher "How do I parallel park? Oh, but I can't turn the wheel, because I'm not at *steering* yet." Fortunately, in this case lifetimes are not required (witness my answer), and the linked question does not address the question as posed anyway (you would have to use `&x - &y` instead of `x - y`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example, the compiler tells you why `x` has been invalidated by the move:

```
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `Vec3`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

In this case, you can simply add `#[derive(Copy)]` to give `Vec3` *copy semantics*:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    pub v: [f64; 3],
}
```

`Copy` is a marker trait that indicates to the compiler that values of a type do not become invalid when they are moved from. A type with this property is said to have copy semantics, while a type that does not implement `Copy` is said to have move semantics. [Is it possible to make a type only movable and not copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253344/is-it-possible-to-make-a-type-only-movable-and-not-copyable/24253573#24253573) and [How does Rust provide move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490670/how-does-rust-provide-move-semantics) explain this concept in more detail.

---

However, you can only implement `Copy` for types that contain only other `Copy` types. If `Vec3` actually held a `Vec` inside it, the compiler would not let you implement `Copy` for it. Fortunately, references do implement `Copy`, so you can instead implement `Sub` for a *reference* to `Vec3`, using the approach described in [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005134/how-do-i-implement-the-add-trait-for-a-reference-to-a-struct)