# How to force borrow a variable for closure? Encoding an f32 in bendy

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

While implementing an encoding trait for bendy I tried the following:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Default, Clone)]
pub struct MyFloot {
    pub density: f32,
}

use bendy::encoding::{Error, ToBencode};

impl ToBencode for MyFloot {
    const MAX_DEPTH: usize = 1;

    fn encode(&self, encoder: bendy::encoding::SingleItemEncoder) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.density
            .to_be_bytes()
            .iter()
            .map(|b| encoder.emit_int(*b));
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

For which the following error is produced:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `encoder`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src\main.rs:17:22
    |
13  |     fn encode(&self, encoder: bendy::encoding::SingleItemEncoder) -> Result<(), Error> {
    |                      ------- captured outer variable
...
17  |             .map(|b| encoder.emit_int(*b));
    |                  --- ^^^^^^^ ------------ `encoder` moved due to this method call
    |                  |   |
    |                  |   move occurs because `encoder` has type `SingleItemEncoder<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |                  captured by this `FnMut` closure
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `encoder`
   --> .cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\bendy-0.3.3\src\encoding\encoder.rs:257:42
    |
257 |     pub fn emit_int<T: PrintableInteger>(self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error> {
    |                                          ^^^^
```

But I cannot  wrap my head around the  move semantics with this..

- Why would the closure take ownership of `encoder` here, [despite the ommited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318218/why-can-i-still-use-a-variable-captured-by-a-move-closure) `move` ?  ( I assume it does )
- Why does it need to move it out of context?
- What does that even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

Firstly, it was not the closure that consumed `encoder`, it was the `emit*` call. The first loop iteration would have consumed it, so that's why the compiler was throwing an error.

Secondly, `encoder` in bendy has the `emit_bytes` function in trait, which can be used here:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Copy, Default, Clone)]
pub struct MyFloot {
    pub density: f32,
}

use bendy::encoding::{Error, ToBencode};

impl ToBencode for MyFloot {
    const MAX_DEPTH: usize = 1;

    fn encode(&self, encoder: bendy::encoding::SingleItemEncoder) -> Result<(), Error> {
        encodert.emit_bytes(self.density.to_be_bytes());
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that is your problem `emit_int` takes `self` instead `&self`, so after the first endian the encoder is dropped

Answer (score 1):

This closure takes ownership of `encoder` because it calls `emit_int`, which needs ownership of `encoder`. `map` requires a closure that can be run an arbitrary number of times, which is why it takes `FnMut` instead of `FnOnce`.

---

Note that `Iterator::map` is lazy, so if this compiled (say, with [`Encoder`](https://docs.rs/bendy/latest/bendy/encoding/struct.Encoder.html)), it wouldn't actually do anything. You would either call `Iterator::for_each`:

```rs
self.density
    .to_be_bytes()
    .iter()
    .for_each(|b| encoder.emit_int(*b));
```

Or call `array::map`:

```rs
self.density
    .to_be_bytes()
    .map(|b| encoder.emit_int(b));
```

Or just use a for loop:

```rs
for b in self.density.to_be_bytes() {
    encoder.emit_int(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why would the closure take ownership of `encoder` here, despite the ommited `move`?

Because the `emit_int` method receives `self` by value:

```
pub fn emit_int<T: PrintableInteger>(self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error>
```

So the value *must* be moved into the closure for this method to be invoked.

`move` on a closure forces the compiler to move referenced variables into the closure, but the absence of `move` *does not forbid* the compiler from moving referenced variables into the closure.  It will still move variables in if they are used in the closure within a context that requires they be moved.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.rs/bendy/0.3.3/bendy/encoding/struct.SingleItemEncoder.html#method.emit_int

At the provided link you can check the documentation of the bendy crate and you will find that the `emit_init` method implemented on the `bendy::encoding::SingleItemEncoder` struct takes `self` as the reciever, meaning that the function takes ownership of the instance of the SingleItemEncoder it is called on as a method. In your case, the parameter `encoder` is such an instance, so when you call the `emit_init` method on it at line 17, ownership of the variable is taken. Thus, rust infers that the closure needs to take ownership of this variable to facilitate this method call, meaning that a move of the variable occurs without having to use the 'move' keyword which forces a move in cases where a move is not necessary.

To understand the concept of a move, please refer to The Book:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#variables-and-data-interacting-with-move

I hope that was helpful